# How to collect a dump using dotnet-dump after garbage collection is finished?

Tags: .net, .net-6.0, dump

I want to collect a dump for .NET 6 app (Windows service) which runs in production environment.
The main goal is to analyze managed memory, but all attempts to collect it were finished with dumps collected in the middle of garbage collection.

I thought, that `dotnet-dump` could help me, but another dump I've got has the same issue.
Is there a wat to tell `dotnet-dump` something like "wait for GC to complete, then collect the dump"?

There is similar question for ProcDump here, but answer is based on performance counter, which is absent on the target machine (and, probably, irrelevant for .NET 6).

Any solutions?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure, but can this help you? https://i.stack.imgur.com/qszro.png

Comment: @TinyWang, actually, I don't know. What I've tried so far were: task manager, procdump, dotnet-dump. All of them created dumps in the middle of GC. I see that this tool also can collect dumps, but what about awating for GC? The problem is that it's a customer's production machine, I just can't tell them "please try another one".

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.pause?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Comment: @HansPassant, as fa as I understood your point, 1) my service must set CanPauseAndContinue to `true`, e.g. inside ctor 2) user can use "Services" snap-in to pause the service and then collect a dump. Right? Never used pause feature for services, will it freeze CLR threads without any affects to used resources, especially, managed heap?

Comment: Just have tested on my machine. Pausing the service does nothing to my working tasks. They work as if there is no any pause command (I see logs are being written).

Answer (score 0):

you can try to the following:

- run dotnet-gcdump collect command. this command will trigger gc and then collects events from gc. in your case you don't care about the generated dump but we are using this to call gc indirectly.
- run dotnet-dump right after running dotnet-gcdump

you can validate this by running dotnet-counters monitor and looking at heap size counter you will see after gcdump heap size is decreasing because of gc.